# WPF application cannot be fully maximized

Tags: wpf, windows-10

I have an application with window properties set to

```
WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None"
```

When I minimize it and maximize again, it not fill whole screen, so Windows start bar is visible and there is a strange margin on bottom and right of app window.

Problem exists only on Windows 10 LTSB 2016. On normal Windows 10 everything seems to be ok.

I tried to force set height and width related to screen resolution and force set Left and Top of window. Didn't help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make my wpf application Full Screen (Cover taskbar and title bar of window)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25499393/make-my-wpf-application-full-screen-cover-taskbar-and-title-bar-of-window)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `ResizeMode=ResizeMode.NoResize` is set on your window, before you change to maximized window.

Comment: You're right. There is no margin anymore, but still Windows start bar is visible.

Comment: I have tested it with a minimal example and setting `WindowState=Maximized` , `WindowStyle=None` and `ResizeMode=NoResize` . In this case the window was real fullscreen and covering the windows taskbar.

Comment: As I said, on normal Windows 10 1809 everything is ok even without ResizeMode, but problem exists on Windows 10 LTSB 2016. It is based on some older build of 10.