# How to hide task bar and maximize window using WPF through Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin.forms, mahapps.metro

I have already tried different options including info in this question [Make my wpf application Full Screen (Cover taskbar and title bar of window)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25499393/make-my-wpf-application-full-screen-cover-taskbar-and-title-bar-of-window/47243845), but nothing helped me
Only **IgnoreTaskbarOnMaximize** property works correct, but it is used from the MahApps, which is not compatible with Xamarin Forms. Maybe you know how to implement IgnoreTaskbarOnMaximize manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is quite simple. If you want to make your application full screen (with taskbar covering) don't set WindowState to Maximized, just change Width and Height like this after `InitializeComponent();`

```
public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  Top = 0;
  Left = 0;
  Height = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
  Width = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;

  Forms.Init();
  LoadApplication(new SharedForms.App());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from [this tutorial on using Xamarin.Forms with WPF](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-wpf-application-using-xamarin-forms/), the Xamarin.Forms application is created from a Window

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : FormsApplicationPage
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Forms.Init();
        LoadApplication(new My.App());
    }
}
```

with or without the respective XAML file (should not matter that much, unless the `InitializeComponent` is not called without a XAML file). *If* there is a XAML file for your window, I'd suppose that [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25499856/2249175) would work out

```xml
<wpf:FormsApplicationPage ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowState="Maximized"  ...>
<!-- Not sure whether the grid is needed in here -->
</wpf:FormsApplicationPage>
```

otherwise you'd have to set the properties from your window class

```cs
public class MainWindow : FormsApplicationPage
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        // whatever there is to be done before

        this.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
        this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;

        Forms.Init();
        LoadApplication(new My.App());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as I already said this and other solutions from the topic below didn't help me.

Comment: @EmiliaLarssen Unfortunately you did not give too many information on *what* you've actually tried. Hence my answer was only a shot in the dark :)

Comment: @EmiliaLarssen Ah, I see what you mean. There is no title bar when I do not initialize the Window as a Xamarin.Forms `FormsApplicationPage`, but as soon as I do, there is a title bar.

Comment: When I tried to test your solution on a new clear WPF app it worked perfectly, but the same modifications on Xamarin Forms through WPF didn't help

Comment: Yes, it what I am talking about)

Comment: @EmiliaLarssen It's quite complicated. There is a workaround of sorts, but this makes more problems than it solves :/

Comment: anyway I like problems