# WPF taskbar still visible in tablet mode in Windows 10

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10

I am working on a WPF application for Windows 10 and I'm trying to set the app in fullscreen and hide the taskbar. I used this code :

```
this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
```

This is working fine in desktop mode. But when switching to tablet mode the taskbar is still visible.

With `this.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;`, the problem is still there...

Comment: Does [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.showintaskbar?view=netframework-4.8) answer your question? Or you mean Window Caption?

Comment: Neither of those. I want my application to be in fullscreen without the Windows taskbar (at the bottom of the screen)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60416733/12888024) then?

Comment: @aepot, nope this doesn't do the trick